# class или static внутри if

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно получить либо

```
class BoldBlot extends Inline {}
```

Либо

```
class BoldBlot extends Inline {
    static create(value) {
        let node = super.create();
        node.setAttribute('url', value);
        return node;
    }
    
    static formats(node) {
            return node.getAttribute('url');
    }
    
}
```

Но проблема в том что если я засовываю if внутрь `class BoldBlot`
то не видит static
, а если снаружи `class BoldBlot`
то не видит сам `BoldBlot`

И как мне тогда это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const BoldBlot = ((flag) => {
    if (flag) {
        return class BoldBlot extends Object {};
    } else {
        return class BoldBlot extends Array {};
    }
});

const arr = new (BoldBlot(false))(2,4,5,6);
const obj = new (BoldBlot(true));

console.log(arr);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Я вроде понял смысл но почему-то он не работает с Inline? пишет что `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '__blot' of undefined` Я просто пытаюсь сократить вот этот код https://codepen.io/quill/pen/vKrBjE. ps метод modules мне не нужен так как я создаю собственные кнопки

Comment: Спасибо я вроде как разобрался

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test {
  static moo() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

↑ Эквивалентно ↓ (* почти, у первого нет prototype)

```
class Test {}

Test.moo = function() {
  "use strict";
  // ...  
}
```

Поэтому можно так:

```
class BoldBlot extends Inline {}

if (smth) {
  BoldBlot.create = function(value) { // <-- static create(value) {
    let node = super.create();
    node.setAttribute('url', value);
    return node;
  };

  BoldBlot.formats = function(node) { // <-- static formats(node) {
    return node.getAttribute('url');
  };
}
```

Если действие происходит внутри какой-то функции, можно наоборот, `if (!smth) return;` и дальше объявлять методы без дополнительной вложенности.

Comment: Я вроде понял но у меня не работает `super.create()` Я правильно понял что он вызывает функцию `BoldBlot.create` что бы зациклить ее.

Comment: @zeni1agent в этом случае `super.create === Inline.prototype.create` — т.е. в классе Inline должен быть не static метод `create() {`

Comment: а как мне получить к нему доступ? просто заменить `super.create` на `Inline.prototype.create` не поможет.

Comment: _* почти, у первого нет prototype_ - какого prototype нету?

Comment: @Grundy У static функции... `Test.moo.prototype // undefined` и не знаю, почему его решили убрать)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, а, это потому что `moo` не функция, а метод. А так как метод не может использоваться в качестве конструктора, то и `prototype` ему ни к чему